# How to split one vendor library out of the vendor file (Vue/Laravel Mix/Web pack)?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

Im using laravel mix/webpack/vue, and want to split out vendor libraries to separate files, but cant seem to do it.

I've used algolia's 'vue instant search' and managed to use dynamic loading to split out each of my components, but cant seem to split that library out from my vendor.js

```
#SearchPage.vue

import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch';
window.Vue.use(InstantSearch);
```

Although code splitting is giving me search-page.js, algolia's vue intant search is still being bundled into the vendor.js

Is there a way I can have my search page component bring in the instant search code, without having it bundled in the vendor.js for the whole site?

Comment: did you find a solution?